# Google API: Access mailbox to query mails

Tags: c#, google-api, gmail-api, service-accounts, google-api-dotnet-client

IDE: MS Visual Studio - C#

Code Screenshot:
[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sLnCI.png)

```
ServiceAccountCredential cred;
        //UserCredential cred;
        string[] scopes = new string[] { GmailService.Scope.GmailLabels, GmailService.Scope.GmailModify, GmailService.Scope.MailGoogleCom };
        using (var stream = new FileStream(@"C:\Users\user\Downloads\iwt-mail-crm-sync-135b79aaca90.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            cred = ServiceAccountCredential.FromServiceAccountData(stream);
            cred.Scopes = scopes;
        }
        var gmailsvc = new GmailService(new Google.Apis.Services.BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = cred,
            ApplicationName = "Gmail immoMail Listener",
        });
        var test = cred.RequestAccessTokenAsync(CancellationToken.None).Result;
        try
        {
            var usr = gmailsvc.Users.GetProfile("me").Execute();
            var lbl = gmailsvc.Users.Labels.List("adress@immowelt.de").Execute();
            var messages = gmailsvc.Users.Messages.List("adress@immowelt.de").Execute();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
```

Error Screenshot:

[image: Error]

error message: The service gmail has thrown an exception. HttpStatusCode is BadRequest. Precondition check failed.

We try to connect google service account via API to a google mailbox to query the mails.
We get a successfull request access token but we are not able to query the mailbox itself.

Answer (score 0):

Precondition failed means that you are trying to use a service account to access a google drive workspace account but have forgotten to delegate a user

```
var credential = GoogleCredential.FromFile(PathToServiceAccountKeyFile)
    .CreateWithUser("User@Yourdomain.com")  // delegate to user on workspace.
    .CreateScoped(new[] {DriveService.ScopeConstants.Drive});
```

Its not enough to just configure domain wide delegation to the service account though workspace, you must also declare the user you want the service account to impersonate.